# Cant get my css to work on all tags in class

Tags: html, css, reactjs

So i got this class called userinfo.js its just some text and looks like this.

```
import React from "react";
import "./Userinfo.css";

export default function Userinfo() {
  return (
    <div className="info-background">
      <div className="userinfo-textbox">
        <p className="heading">User Information</p>
        <br />
        <p>
          This website is intended to be used for educational purposes only. The
          methods of remote diagnosis of diseases of the oral cavity are new and
          almost no previous studies or material exists on the subject matter.
        </p>
        <br />
        <p>
          To receive an accurate diagnosis, make sure to first fill out the
          “Declaration of health” form. After this is done navigate to the
          “Remote Diagnosis” page where you fill out information regarding your
          current oral health issue, and upload images (if you want) relating to
          the issue.
        </p>
        <br />
        <p>
          bla bla
        </p>
        <br />
        <p>
          bla bla
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And it got a css file name userinfo.css that looks like this.

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=PT+Sans&display=swap");

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "PT Sans", sans-serif;
}

.info-background{
  background-image: url("../../images/dimdisc.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: #fff;
}

.userinfo-textbox {
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 500px;
  height: 600px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 20px;
  object-fit: contain;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.heading {
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Now everything works fine except the info-background div. It is not affected by the css at all and i have no idea why. Its a react project btw. Any idea whats going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.userinfo-textbox` has position absolute so `.info-background` does not take the height of the textbox.

Adding height and width to the `.info-background` CSS will make it show.

**OR**

You can make your `.info-background` position absolute and give `.userinfo-textbox` position relative. In this case, `.info-background` will in expand according to `.userinfo-textbox`

You can find more details regarding the `position` attribute [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#values)

> **absolute**

> The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout.

Comment: yessss im getting closer. its starting to show but not perfectly but thank you very much!

Comment: Glad I could help. If my answer (or any other answer) guided you to your final solution, make sure you mark it as accepted so that others can benefit from the advice that helped you. Thanks!